# Black screen issue using unity 5 with Gear VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I'm working on unity-5. If I try making simple apps using unity for android and desktop, It works fine. But now, I'm using unity-5 with for Gear VR apps. Now, as I install the app on Android device using "Build and run" feature then only black screen is shown on android app start. It not even shows splash screen showing "made with Unity".

```
Basic settings:
Texture compression: ASTC
Min sdk: 19
Target API level: Max (currently 7.1, Nogut)
Virtually supported: true
VR sdk: Oculus
```

Note: If I uncheck "Virtually reality supported" from player settings, app works fine as usual.

Comment: What is the unity version? Please don't say "Unity 5". The full version....

Comment: @Programmer Unity 2017.1.0f3 Personal (64 bit)

Comment: The title and the body of your questions says "Unity 5".....

Comment: Are you sure you are not loading an empty scene? Maybe the wrong scene. Check the build settings to verify this.

Comment: @Programmer Is it not from unity 5 series?

Comment: @Programmer yes, 100% sure. I've just one scene in current app and  checked the scene on camera too.

Comment: No. After 4.6, there there was 5. After 5.6 there could have been 6 but Unity changed the naming convention.The unity3d tag is enough. I do think you should try **2017. *2***. If that does not work please file for a bug report.

Comment: @Programmer OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the oculus package that you are using.

Use Oculus utilities 1.15.0 instead of 1.16.0(which is still in beta version the blackscreen issue is not fixed yet).

I hope this solves your problem.